# Rewriting a Silverlight project into javascript, wcf involved

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf, silverlight

There is a c# project, hosting several wcf services,including basichttpbinding and nettcpbinding.
And a silverlight project, consuming the services. For the nettcpbinding part, it establishes a connection with the server. When the server gets new data elsewhere, it send the data to the clients connected ,via callback channel.

About silverlight, I know nothing but it runs at the client. I think this is the important thing: since sliverlight runs at the client and is written in c#, it's easy to consume wcf services, including duplex ones.

My task is to rewrite the silverlight project, mainly using javascript.
For the non-duplex part, I wrote several ashx handlers, and invoke it with ajax. (Is that right?)

But for the duplex part, after reading some posts I found polling seems the only way. When the server receive new data, it stores it somewhere, and the client invoke a handler every several seconds, the handler then returns the new data. So the server can't send the data to the client actively.
Am I doing it rightly, or any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

[Web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets) is the new HTML5 standard that supports push from server to client.  (Actually web sockets are probably superior to the Silverlight duplex classes, which don't use true push under the hood but rather old-fashioned long polling with periodic "keep-alive" signals from the client.)

I'd suggest taking a look at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr), which is an ASP.Net component that wraps web socket functionality, and also "falls back to other compatible techniques for older browsers".

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar position a couple years ago: I had a Silverlight client talking to a duplex WCF server that I needed to port to JavaScript/HTML5. The question was, "What do we do about the backend?" I settled on exactly the same scenario that @McGarnagle describes, namely, switching to [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) on the backend, and using the SignalR JavaScript client to communicate to that backend. I could have spent a great deal of time rearchitecting the WCF backend to share logic with SignalR, but because we were effectively abandoning our Silverlight client, it ended up making more sense just cutting and pasting the code powering the WCF service into the new SignalR hubs.

About the only thing I didn't like with SignalR (at the time) is that it only used dynamic objects to communicate to the client. I preferred (and continue to prefer) static, compile-time checking. I think there are ways to do that now with SignalR and TypeScript, but I haven't investigated them recently.

The primary alternative, by the way, that I investigated was using JavaScript to talk to the same WCF service. While there were supposedly some ways to get that to work, it didn't seem like they were very mature and were unlikely to be well supported going forward. SignalR is definitely the approach you'll want to use if you're trying to use C# on the backend and JavaScript on the client and need two-way communication: steer well clear of WCF in that scenario.